# What are acceptable parameters for Dimensions.get in react-native

Tags: react-native

According to the [documentation for the Dimensions API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html), the `get` method takes a string, but apart from 'window' and 'screen' I can't find any reference to which keys are actually available. Is there such documentation out there? Can I use IDs somehow for example? Or is it only 'window' and 'screen' really?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, React native only support `window` and `screen` in `Dimension.get('')` method.

You can check the source code Dimension.js at below link.

[Github Dimension.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/228a1fe7d48d57a0fbb2d852135ef94247198aaa/Libraries/Utilities/Dimensions.js)

Comment: All I can say for sure looking at that code is that window and screen are being initialised by that class, but I can't say there is nothing else coming through later on, or even at `var dimensions = UIManager.Dimensions`.

Comment: You can check respective platform dependent code there. They get specific window width and height

Comment: dimensions.screen = dimensions.window; will show that it's getting window key